# How to add UIScrollView elegantly to a View Controller that's full of other views (buttons, textfields, etc) already with Interface Builder

Tags: uiscrollview, ios8, interface-builder, autolayout

So I realized my app needs `UIScrollView`, but I already have a bunch of other views on my View Controller. I know in order for the scroll view to work, I have to have my views as child view of this scroll view. But the constraints between my already existing views are perfectly set up with each other, so I don't want to move every single one of them under scroll view and add every constraint all over again. Is there an elegant way to add scroll view in and keep existing views' relation at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do add a scrollview without having to redo all the constraints.

Add a scrollview on your viewcontroller in storyboard

Open your storyboard as sourcecode find the `<scene>` of your viewcontroller and find `<scrollview>` under `<subviews>` 
[image: opening sourcecode]

add `<subviews></subviews>` and  `<constraints></constraints>` inside `<scrollview>`
[image: adding subview and constraints]

copy all other xml inside the `<subviews>` to `<scrollView><subviews>`

copy all constraints and move it inside constraints tag we created inside scrollview. 
[image: moving subviews and constraints]

Replace the id of main view with that of scrollview in this copied constraints
[image: superview id]

[image: scrollview id]

save and open storyboard as interface builder and add constraint to scrollview with respect to Superview

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this approach is very error prone as it involves lots of copying and pasting. Also merely changing ids after copy and paste may not completely solve the problem...

Comment: So I went with your suggestion. All the subviews of scroll view did remain same distance with each other like originally, but I had to do adjustments of constraints on each subview in interface builder because many constraints can't be solved automatically. It's a workaround, but I think there must be more elegant way to solve this.